# Using Tensor double dots in Latex, with tensor package

Tags: amsmath, tensor

I am currently struggling to find a way to write :
[image]

I know of `\cdots` and `\cdot` but the output is one dot and 3 dots but not two. What is a possible solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\mathbin{\cdot\cdot}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own symbol; since it is a binary operation, use `\mathbin`; the `\cdot` symbol can then be repeated twice.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbfsl}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{bx}{sl} % for boldface slanted sans serif

\newcommand{\vct}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\tns}[1]{\mathsfbfsl{#1}}
\newcommand{\cddot}{\mathbin{{\cdot}{\cdot}}}

\begin{document}

$\vct{T}=\tns{C}\cddot\vct{E}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed and good answer.